# Invalid host header on mern stack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, open-source, mern, development-environment

```
"proxy": "https://mango-artist-rmdnr.pwskills.app:5000",
```

I am adding this code to connect my `frontend` with backend then it showing invalid `host header`.

My backend is running on port 5000 and frontend react is running on port `3000`.

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts start --public YOUR_LOCAL_IP_ADDRESS"
}
```

I use this in my frontend's package.json file then it is running fine but it is running on `port 3000` not on `port 5000.`

Answer (score 0):

It may be a cross-origin error!
add this to your backend code

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000"); 
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

and use your actual frontend address instead of `http://localhost:3000`.

on top of these try removing the --public YOUR_LOCAL_IP_ADDRESS argument from your frontend's start script in package.json, since it's not necessary for running the frontend and may cause issues. You can leave the script as `"start": "react-scripts start"`.

Finally, make sure that your proxy is correctly configured in your frontend's package.json file:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
```

This tells the frontend to proxy requests to the backend running on port 5000. Make sure to restart both the frontend and backend servers after making these changes.

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (Bad Gateway)                                                             After doing this showing above error.

Comment: Have you tried using npm install cors and using it on backend and adding proxy to your script too instead of the first method I mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

create-react-app docs mention this issue in docs. This is the link ["Invalid Host Header" Errors After Configuring Proxy](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/#invalid-host-header-errors-after-configuring-proxy)